# What should I change in FindFirstFile function to make it show me full file names?

Tags: c++

I'm a student currently learning c++ and I'm doing a course project.

I'm told to use FindFirstFile function but I can't really understand how it functions and almost blindly made it work somehow. Yet it only shows me the first letters of the files' names. What should I change to make it show me the full names so I could use it later in the program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    system("chcp 1251");

    hf = FindFirstFile(L"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\*", &FindFileData);
    if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error opening files or no files found!");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Found file: %s", FindFileData.cFileName);
            printf("\n");
        } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The example of what it shows: [example of program's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd9Uk.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - Having problems with a simple example of FindFirstFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475540/c-having-problems-with-a-simple-example-of-findfirstfile)

Comment: You got the FindFirstFile() call correct, properly using L"" to indicate a wide string.  But not in the printf() call, use %ls.

Comment: %ls in printf solved the problem with display of names!

Answer (score 2):

Like a wise man said I should've used %ls modificator in printf as I indicate long string in FindFirstFile but trying to just output regular string

Comment: Good call.  There's probably a compiler warning for that.

Comment: Surprisingly there was none so that's the reason I did not see it

Comment: Did you try [`/W4`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-160)?  It's often a good bet.